# How to split the data into training and test sets?

Tags: database, machine-learning, weka

One approach to split the data into two disjoint sets, one for training and one for tests is taking the first 80% as the training set and the rest as the test set. Is there another approach to split the data into training and test sets?

** For example, I have a data contains 20 attributes and 5000 objects. Therefore, I will take 12 attributes and 1000 objects as my training data and 3 attributes from the 12 attributes as test set. Is this method correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's invalid. You would always use all features in all data sets. You split by "objects" (examples).

It's not clear why you are taking just 1000 objects and trying to extract a training set from that. What happened to the other 4000 you threw away?

Train on 4000 objects / 20 features. Cross-validate on 500 objects / 20 features. Evaluate performance on the remaining 500 objects/ 20 features.

Answer (score 1):

If your training produces a classifier based on 12 features, it could be (very) hard to evaluate its performances on a test set based only on a subset of these features (your classifier is expecting 12 inputs and you'll give only 3).

[Feature/attribute selection/extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) is important if your data contains many redundant or irrelevant features. So you could identify and use only the most informative features (maybe 12 features) but your training/validation/test sets should be based on the same number of features (e.g. since you're mentioning weka  [Why do I get the error message 'training and test set are not compatible'?](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Why+do+I+get+the+error+message+%27training+and+test+set+are+not+compatible%27%3F)).

Remaining on a training/validation/test split (*holdout method*), a problem you can face is that the samples might not be representative.

For example, some classes might be represented with very few instance or even with no instances at all.

A possible improvement is stratification: sampling for training and testing within classes. This ensures that each class is represented with approximately equal proportions in both subsets.

However, by partitioning the available data into fixed training/test set, you drastically reduce the number of samples which can be used for learning the model. An alternative is [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29).